# How to instruct xgboost in caret to use mlogloss for optimization

Tags: r, parameters, classification, xgboost

I have a multiclass problem: For example,  we can take the dataset `mtcars` dataset and we want to predict number of cylinders `cyl`.

```
data(mtcars)
```

I want to use `xgboost` and fit it using the `caret` package. For that I create grid for hyperparameters using

```
xgb_grid_param = expand.grid(
  nrounds = 1000,
  eta = c(0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
  max_depth = c(2, 4),
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree =1,
  min_child_weight =1  
)
```

I can create training control parameters as

```
xgb_tr_ctrl = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  repeats =2,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",
  allowParallel = TRUE
```

)

When I then try to run the `train` function in `caret` using:

```
model <- train(factor(cyl)~., data = mtcars, method = "xgbTree",
         trControl = xgb_grid_param, tuneGrid=xgb_grid_param)
```

I get the error ::

```
 Error in trControl$classProbs && any(classLevels !=  make.names(classLevels)) :
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

How do I fix this error and how do I instruct `xgbTree` to use `mlogloss` to optimize the learning.

Answer (score 0):

For another method I could solve "invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'" by setting the label attribute as last column of the data frame / matrix.